# Mysql insert new row

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Now, I have a table with _id(primary key, int auto increase) and had some rows. I want to insert new data into table but want move up to first row of table.

Ex : before insert data table had rows

_id | name

1 David

2 Tom

3 Same

And I want result after inserted

_id | name

4 Majin

1 David

2 Tom

3 Same

I need help, Thanks :)

Comment: There are no order in a db table. Use ORDER BY to get the select result in a wanted order.

Comment: Sorry, I doing crawl data from website and notify update to DB when have new data so when insert it, i want move up to first row of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY`

`ORDER BY ASC |DESC`

like that :-

```
select * from table order by (id=4) DESC,id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But ORDER BY ASC |DESC result no desire

Comment: select * from table order by (id=4) DESC,id ASC

Comment: try this query please

Comment: move up to rows of table without ORDER BY is not possible